# Is there a semiprime ring (with 1) with non-zero singular ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I study semiprime rings and modules and I haven't found an example of a semiprime ring with non-zero singular ideal nor I haven't been able to prove that every semiprime ring is nonsingular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are examples, but they might be hard to come by.

The only one I am aware of at the moment is an example given by Bergman which is a prime ring but is not left or right nonsingular. According to Lam, the details appear in *Rings with chain conditions* by Chatters and Hajarnavis pp 27-30.

For commutative rings, both notions become equivalent to the ring being reduced, so there is no such example there.

Comment: Thank you, I will check the Chatters paper.